# What would be the best way to stucture MVC model and data access layer code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using EF Code first to access data in MVC. What would be best place to put the DbContext and ObjectContext code   :-

-- Create a new Folder / Area with a different namespace and put the Code in it.

-- Create a DbContext  Dal project outside the MVC project and add reference to it.

Wondering what is the best way ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get advantage of TDD(Test driven design i.e., design on the fly) I would suggest to go with different layers(most importantly it has to happen by keeping an eye on abstraction and separation of concerns. i.e., breaking the system in to its structural-elements, architectural-components, sub-systems, sub-assemblies)

Please follow below great answers(for similar type of questions)

> [Clean solution (project) structure with EF, Repositories, Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283090/clean-solution-project-structure-with-ef-repositories-entities?rq=1)
>
> [Whats a recommended solution structure for a somewhat large website in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865543/whats-a-recommended-solution-structure-for-a-somewhat-large-website-in-asp-net)